# Is this patent still valid (inventer still have exclusive rights)?

Tags: rights

In reference to the patent: [US5517187](https://www.google.com/patents/US5517187)

My question is if this patent is still valid or already expired? I mean, can the invention of this patent be used into my product or the invetor still have the exclusive rights of it?

Answer (score 2):

This patent has expired. Anyone is free to practice what is described in the claims. Always understand that other relevant patents may exist.